# Do older versions of PHP/MYSQL have defaults for NOT NULL columns?

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-orm

Earlier today I setup a new dev server for our project in a newer version of MYSQL and PHP (5.7 compared to 5.6 for mysql, 5.6 over 5.5 for php) I've discovered something  odd.

Some of our inserts (through Kohana's ORM system) don't have entries for all the NOT NULL columns without default values. This strangely doesn't cause an error in the current development server, the row column is populated with an empty string. On the other hand, in the new server it causes an error (predictably).

The codebase is the exact same, using the Kohana framework version 3. Just to be clear I'm a new member of the team, I was in no way involved in the making of this.

Comment: No, there is no change in the language or the database server implementation that would do this. It is likely there is a change to the table structure or something in the ORM you are using. Would you produce a `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for this table for each server? Please edit the output into your question using a code block.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've found the issue. Apparently the app wasn't developed using strict mode.

Comment: Mysql 5.6 onward Strict mode is default on, it was causing same issues on my new serve as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but the entire application was developed without using strict mode on mysql. This makes it so omitted not null columns are given a default value like an empty string.